# What is the closest alternative for TeXnicCenter + SumatraPDF on mac?

Tags: texmaker, viewers, texniccenter, forward-inverse-search

I am getting a mac soon, and I am freaked out the fact that I won't be able to use my very much familiar TeXnicCenter + SumatraPDF magic tools.

I googled around and decided to switch to TeXMaker, which is available for both pc and mac. It got some nice features, but frequently freeze when I am editing my dissertation document that involves multiple active files. And the forward-inverse-search on the multiple file situation does not work.

Does any one happen to know a good alternative for XnicCenter + SumatraPDF on mac? Thanks very much!

Comment: Try TexShop on the Mac. It comes with MacTeX.

Comment: Choose as per your taste from a very nicely maintained [biglist](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list) post [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/15717)